# CSS3 animation sequence not working

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a simple CSS3 animation that fades in and out:

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

I also have three spans with IDs that I want to fade into each other, only displaying one at a time.

```
<h3>
  <span id="first">First.</span> 
  <span id="second">Second.</span> 
  <span id="third">Third.</span>
</h3>

h3 {
  position: relative;
}

h3 span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.025;
}

h3 span#first {
  animation: pulse 5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

h3 span#second {
  animation: pulse 5s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

h3 span#third {
  animation: pulse 5s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 10s;
}
```

I've set each `span`'s animation to last 5 seconds, while the second and third have 5- and 10-second delays, respectively, to start once the prior has ended, but this isn't the result and the second and third `span`s load at the same time. How can I achieve this?

Demo: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mBqKWm)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On the pen I see first, then first second, then all 3. All 3 continues forever, is this not the behaviour you wanted?

Comment: you don't have to make the dealy = the time of the animation .. they will behave the same at the end -- check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the overall time for all three spans as the animation time - 15 seconds, and adjust the keyframes accordingly to take only one third of the overall time from opacity zero to 1 and back to 0 (5 seconds / 33%):

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    16.67% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    33.33% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

h3 {
  position: relative;

  span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.025;

    &#first {
      animation: pulse 15s infinite ease-in-out;
    }

    &#second {
      animation: pulse 15s infinite ease-in-out;
      animation-delay: 5s;
    }

    &#third {
      animation: pulse 15s infinite ease-in-out;
      animation-delay: 10s;
    }
  }
}
```

Here it is in a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzOraW

Comment: I see! I like this explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to make the delay equal to the time of the animation as the **second element** will be have the same animation as the **first element** after **one itertation** (5s). You need to make the delay equal to half the time of the animation. Here is an example with only 2 :

```css
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

h3 {
  position: relative;
}

h3 span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.025;
}

h3 span#first {
  animation: pulse 5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

h3 span#second {
  animation: pulse 5s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  <span id="first">First.</span> 
  <span id="second">Second.</span> 
</h3>
```

and for 3 you can try this :

```css
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    33% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    66% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

h3 {
  position: relative;
}

h3 span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.025;
}

h3 span#first {
  animation: pulse 6s infinite ease-in-out;
}

h3 span#second {
  animation: pulse 6s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
h3 span#third {
  animation: pulse 6s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  <span id="first">First.</span> 
  <span id="second">Second.</span> 
  <span id="third">Third.</span>
</h3>
```